# Backpack for laravel -> I can't get + Add Inline Create

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I want to use the **Inline Create functionality of Backpack** for Laravel but the button "Add +" doesn't shows up.

I have a **1 to n relationship**

The primary model is **Inscription** and the secondary is **InscriptionProduct**

This is my code:

*Models\Inscription*

```php
...
class Inscription extends Model
{
 
    public function product() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\InscriptionProduct');
    }
...
```

*Models\InscriptionProduct*

```php
...
class InscriptionProduct extends Model
{

    public function inscription()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Inscription::class);
    }
...
```

*Http\Controllers\Admin\InscriptionProductCrudController*

```php
...
class InscriptionProductCrudController extends CrudController
{
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\ListOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\CreateOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\UpdateOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\DeleteOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\ShowOperation;

    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\InlineCreateOperation;
...
```

*Http\Controllers\Admin\InscriptionCrudController*

```php
...
class InscriptionCrudController extends CrudController
{

    protected function setupCreateOperation()
    {
      ...
        $this->crud->addField([
            'type' => "relationship",
            'name' => 'product',
            'ajax' => true,
            'inline_create' => true,
            // 'data_source' => backpack_url('/admin/inscription-product/inline/create'),
            // 'data_source' => backpack_url('inscription/fetch/inscription-product'),
            // 'inline_create' => [ 'entity' => 'inscriptionproduct' ]
            // These 3 commented lines are alternatives also tried with no results
        ]);
...
```

The Relationship is well constructed because I can see the Products I have created via the CRUD of InscriptionProduct

[image: The Relationship is well constructed because I can see the Products i have created via the CRUD of InscriptionProduct]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I solve it to, in your main CrudController, you should call the InLineCreate just below CreateOperation.

```
use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\CreateOperation { store as traitStore; }
use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\InlineCreateOperation { store as traitStore; }
```

Also in my secondary CrudController I had to create a fetch function, something I did

```
  protected function fetchFeatures()
    {
        return $this->fetch([
            'model' => \App\Models\Features::class, // required
            'searchable_attributes' => ['name', 'slug'],
            'query' => function($model) {
                return $model;
            } // to filter the results that are returned
        ]);
        return $this->traitFetch();
    }
```

Comment: I doesn't work

I followed https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-operation-fetch

Now I have, inside InscriptionProductCrudController

`use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\CreateOperation { store as traitStore; }
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\InlineCreateOperation { store as traitStore; }`

Comment: In InscriptionCrudController:
`use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\FetchOperation;
...
protected function fetchInscriptionProduct()
    {
        return $this->fetch([
            'model' => \App\Models\InscriptionProduct::class,
            'searchable_attributes' => ['name'],
            'query' => function($model) {
                return $model;
            }
        ]);
    }`

Comment: I get an 405 error at admin/inscription/fetch/inscription-product
Telling me that the GET method is not compatible, only for POST, so the route is well created

Comment: Also in
setupCreateOperation:
`$this->crud->addField([
            'type' => "relationship",
            'name' => 'product',
            'ajax' => true,
            'inline_create' => true,
            'data_source' => backpack_url('inscription/fetch/inscription-product'),
        ]);`